# Trying to get SharePoint sites for given current user

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to retrieve SharePoint sites that are available for given users through Microsoft Graph API. I looked into Graph API User (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) and noticed that there is a relationship between user and site (sites). However, when I tried to use that one in Graph Explorer, I got the error "Unsupported segment type."

Request: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/sites`

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users/{user_id}/sites",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "cf9dedff-5642-4a77-a179-3d63d2921a8a",
        "date": "2017-05-17T19:46:29"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

That was a documentation bug, the /sites/ collection is not available on the user object. I've committed a change to the docs to clean up the user object description and remove that reference.

I am curious what sort of information you'd want to see returned back from a query for /sites on a user. Are you just looking for all sites the user can access? You can accomplish that using the sites search API:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search={query}
```

Which returns you all sites the user can access that match the query text. If you leave the query text as an empty string, you receive a list of sites the user has access to.

Comment: If I leave the query text as an empty string  in site search API (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?search=""), I got an error "An identifier was expected at position 0." The site search API expects an argument is not null or empty string.

Comment: Don't use quotes, just leave it empty, like this: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?search=

Comment: I tried that and got error in Graph Explorer - Expression expected at position 0 in ''.

Comment: Ah, interesting. It looks like there is a bug in the beta version. This query works if you change beta to v1.0: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=

Comment: I tried that query with v1.0. It works. I noticed that the query returns all documents and sites that given users can access to. Is there any how, I can search only for SharePoint sites? The team I work with is interested in using the Graph API to search for SharePoint sites for given user.